# Generating Public key from Google Oauth2 v3 Certs

Tags: python-2.7, rsa, public-key, google-openid, google-oauth

I don't have much experience with Cryptography. I am developing OpenID Connect Client(RP). For signature verification I want public key. Considering example of Google, It provides public keys [here](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs). Now you can observe n, e there. Using PyCrypto RSA for constructing public key from n and e. Problem is the values are in string. I tried to convert n by decoding with base64 first and then converting to long but not succeeded. Can someone help that what should I do for converting the value of n, e provided by Google for constructing the public key for signature verification?